# CMake tutorial Step 4 install example is not working as expected

Tags: cmake

I'm following this CMake tutorial : https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/index.html
At Step 4, https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/Installing%20and%20Testing.html install is not working as expected. Not sure what is done wrongly by me

I made changes suggested to CMakeLists.txt and from build dir I ran config, build and then tried to install using prefix. Install is giving below error

```
(base) xxx@xxx-ThinkPad-T470p: $ cmake ../Step4 -DUSE_MYMATH=ON
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/xxx/work/CMake_examples/cmake-3.24.1-tutorial-source/Step4_build
(base) xxx@xxx-ThinkPad-T470p: $ cmake --build .
[ 50%] Built target MathFunctions
[100%] Built target Tutorial
(base) xxx@xxx-ThinkPad-T470p: $ cmake --install . --prefix /tmp/testinstall
CMake Error: The source directory "/tmp/testinstall" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

Why is cmake expecting CMakeLists.txt in install directory?

Library CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(MathFunctions mysqrt.cxx)

# state that anybody linking to us needs to include the current source dir
# to find MathFunctions.h, while we don't.
target_include_directories(MathFunctions
          INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
          )

install(TARGETS MathFunctions DESTINATION lib)
install(FILES MathFunctions.h DESTINATION include)
```

Main CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

# set the project name and version
project(Tutorial VERSION 1.0)

# specify the C++ standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

# should we use our own math functions
option(USE_MYMATH "Use tutorial provided math implementation" ON)

# configure a header file to pass some of the CMake settings
# to the source code
configure_file(TutorialConfig.h.in TutorialConfig.h)

# add the MathFunctions library
if(USE_MYMATH)
  add_subdirectory(MathFunctions)
  list(APPEND EXTRA_LIBS MathFunctions)
endif()

# add the executable
add_executable(Tutorial tutorial.cxx)

target_link_libraries(Tutorial PUBLIC ${EXTRA_LIBS})

# add the binary tree to the search path for include files
# so that we will find TutorialConfig.h
target_include_directories(Tutorial PUBLIC
                           "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}"
                           )

install(TARGETS Tutorial DESTINATION bin)
install(FILES "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/TutorialConfig.h"
  DESTINATION include
  )
```

Cmake Version output

```
(base) xxx@xxx-ThinkPad-T470p: $ cmake --version
cmake version 3.10.2
```

Comment: Did you already tried to clear the build directory and rerun your three commands? According to the [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html#variable:CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX) the install command is correct.

Comment: Yes. I tried clean target and re-tried configure, build and install with same result.

Comment: Then please attach the CMakeLists.txt file to your question. It's hard to guess its content from the console output. BTW, what CMake version are you using? Type `cmake --version` in the console to find out.

Comment: Added two CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Your cmake is too old for the `--install` command syntax. `--install` was added to CMake in version 3.15 so you need to install a newer version.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your time! After upgrade to latest (3.24.1) install worked. but then CMake tutorial files needs to update  this line "cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)" at least for install step. thanks vre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cmake is too old for the `--install` command syntax.

`--install` was added to CMake in version 3.15 so you need to install a newer version.

CMake version 3.20 greatly improved handling unknown option arguments (see issue tracker [entry](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/21352)). Older versions tried to handle one of the arguments as your sources directory. That's why you see the error message complaining about a missing CMakeLists.txt file in your install directory.